# Can I add SHA-1 fingerprint to keystore certificate?

Tags: android, keystore, sha1

I have a keystore certificate and password of the same from previous vendor. Now I have made some changes in app and wants to publish it. I have generated the release apk as well but Google Maps stopped working. I'm pretty sure it is issue with keystore certificate because it has different SHA-1 fingerprint. Can I add my SHA-1 fingerprint to keystore certificate? Can anyone guide me how to work around this?

Comment: The fingerprint is calculated on certificate content, so it can not be changed. Why do you suppose the certificate fingerprint has changed?